# Stroke doesn't draw if I write to it after getImageData. Do they conflict with each other?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am simply drawing three lines with html inputs and canvas. But I want to draw two of them with the `putimagedata` method and the other one with the `stroke` method.

If I use `stroke` after I draw with the `putimagedata` method, the stroke doesn't draw anything. The only way it draws is if I put my stroke method just before `getimagedata` method.

Are these two conflicting with each other or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my js code:

```js
function updateCanvas() {
  var startTime = performance.now()
  var first = document.querySelector('input[name="first"]:checked').value;
  var second = document.querySelector('input[name="second"]:checked').value;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value);
  var end = parseInt(document.getElementById("end").value);
  var byuk = parseInt(document.getElementById("byuk").value);
  var syuk = parseInt(document.getElementById("syuk").value);
  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // THIS IS THE PLACE IT WORKS
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.moveTo(0, 200 + byuk);
  ctx.lineTo(399, 200 + syuk);
  ctx.stroke();
  //

  var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);


  function drawPixel(x, y, r, g, b, a) {
    var index = (x + y * canvasWidth) * 4;
    canvasData.data[index + 0] = r;
    canvasData.data[index + 1] = g;
    canvasData.data[index + 2] = b;
    canvasData.data[index + 3] = a;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= 400; i++) {
    drawPixel(i, 200, 50, 50, 50, 255);
  }

  if (start == end) {

    // THIS IS THE PLACE IT DOESNT DRAW EVEN IF STATEMENT WORKS

    //

    var y = 200;
    for (var i = 0; i <= byuk; i++) {
      drawPixel(0, y, 255, 0, 0, 255);
      y++;
    }
    var y2 = 200;
    for (var i = 0; i <= syuk; i++) {
      drawPixel(399, y2, 255, 0, 0, 255);
      y2++;
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);
  var endTime = performance.now()

  console.log(`Call to doSomething took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`)
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #F7B054;
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  #canvas{
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/cizim.css" />
        <title>Line</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
<table align="center" width="1200" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="500"><div align="center"><canvas width ="400" height="400" id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
          
        </canvas>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>  
          </td>
      <td><table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Başlangıç Mesneti:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="msm" name="first" value="msm" checked="checked">
                    <label for="css">Mafsallı Sabit Mesnet</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="mhm" name="first" value="mhm">
                    <label for="javascript">Mafsallı Hareketli Mesnet</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="ank" name="first" value="ank">
                    <label for="html">Ankastre Mesnet</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Bitiş Mesneti:</label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="msm" name="second" value="msm" checked="checked">
                    <label for="css">Mafsallı Sabit Mesnet</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="mhm" name="second" value="mhm">
                    <label for="javascript">Mafsallı Hareketli Mesnet</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="ank" name="second" value="ank">
                    <label for="html">Ankastre Mesnet</label>
                </td>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Başlangıç:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="start" name="fname"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Bitiş:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="end" name="sname"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Başlangıç Yükü:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="byuk" name="sname"></td>
              </tr>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><label for="fname">Bitiş Yükü:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="syuk" name="sname"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><button id="myBtn" onclick="updateCanvas()">Hesapla</button></td>
              </tr>
          
          
          
          </tbody>
          </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


        <div align="center">

            
<script src="canvas.js"></script>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please add your html to the snippet so that it demonstrates your issue

Comment: Oddly, you never use `stroke` AFTER you use `putImageData` - have you put the correct code in the question?

Comment: I added ther snippet, in orfer to draw for clarification first 2 input fields must be same btw. When i put these codes from beginpath to stroke to the place i commented it doesnt draw the this line which connects the other 2.

Comment: As noted, there is no call to `stroke` after using `putImageData`, so I think this might be a misunderstanding regarding `getImageData`, which  returns a _copy_ of the image data. So, doing something like `const x = ctx.getImageData(); ctx.stroke(...); ctx.putImageData(x, 0, 0);` will overwrite the update to the canvas made by `ctx.stroke(...)` ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Ok with the help of Bravo and msbit i figured it out what is wrong. I didnt fully understand the logic of getimagedata and putimagedata. After moving stroke after putimage it started working inside if statement. I didnt know putimagedata will overwrite stroke command. Thank you.